# Jenkins doesn't change directory through sh 'cd directory' command

Tags: jenkins, fastlane

I use mac. I have ios and android projects on react-native and created fastlane scripts for each project. Now I want to automate builds with Jenkins in pipeline, so I have Jenkins file. In work space of Jenkins I have to go to `ios` folder, and execute fastlane script.

But the problem is that Jenkins doesn't change directory with command `sh 'cd ios'`. I can see it because I execute `pwd` command before and after change directory command.

I tried to use symbolic link, run command in my current process with the "dot" command (like `sh '. cd ios'`), tried to use full path to ios folder. But all of this did not bring success :(

So, why Jenkins doesn't change the directory with `sh 'cd ios'` command? How can I cope with it ? Thank you in advance.

Here is my script

```
pipeline {
```

agent any

tools {nodejs "Jenkins_NodeJS"}

stages {

```
stage('Pulling git repo'){
  steps{
    git(
      url: 'url_to_git_repo',
      credentialsId: 'jenkins_private_key2',
      branch: 'new_code'
    )
  }
}

stage('Prepare') {
    steps{
      sh 'npm install -g yarn'
      sh 'yarn install'
    }
}

stage('Building') {
    steps{
      sh 'cd /Users/igor/.jenkins/workspace/MobileAppsPipeline/ios'
      sh 'ls -l'
      sh '/usr/local/bin/fastlane build_and_push'
    }
}
```

}
}

Comment: Try to use absolute path. Also, please post your code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This because of all Jenkins commands run in directory [Jenkins home]/workspace/[your pipeline name] (I hope you use pipeline).

If you have some need to change directory then your script should be like:

```
node {
    stage("Test") {
        sh script:'''
          #!/bin/bash
          echo "This is start $(pwd)"
          mkdir hello
          cd ./hello
          echo "This is $(pwd)"
        '''
    }
}
```

And your output will be:

[image]

Second `sh` command will start in workspace directory.

Comment: Yes, I had to type like this
`sh script:'''
          our_actions
        '''`

@ozlevka thank you!

Answer (score 24):

Just for the record because it is more descriptive and you are using descriptive pipelines ;)

If you want to do some work in specific directory, there is a `step` for that:

```
stage('Test') {
  steps {  
    dir('ios') { // or absolute path
      sh '/usr/local/bin/fastlane build_and_push'
    }
  }
}
```

The following example

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('mkdir') {
            steps {
              sh'mkdir ios && touch ios/HelloWorld.txt'  
            }
        }
        stage('test') {
            steps {
              dir('ios') {
                  sh'ls -la'
              }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

produces the outut

```
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (mkdir)
[Pipeline] sh
+ mkdir ios 6073 touch ios/HelloWorld.txt
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (test)
[Pipeline] dir
Running in /stuff/bob/workspace/test-1/ios
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ ls -la
total 12
drwxrwxr-x 3 bob bob 4096 Sep 20 13:34 .
drwxrwxr-x 6 bob bob 4096 Sep 20 13:34 ..
drwxrwxr-x 2 bob bob 4096 Sep 20 13:34 HelloWorld.txt
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // dir
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
```

Answer (score 2):

Run your commands using below format, thats how any shell script can be run through in Jenkins file.

// Shell format:
sh """
 #!/bin/bash
 your command
"""

Example:

```
    sh """ 
    #!/bin/bash
    cd /Users/igor/.jenkins/workspace/MobileAppsPipeline/ios
    ls -l
    /usr/local/bin/fastlane build_and_push
    """
```